# Is there a way to use a lambda/reduce function to find the highest value in my elements?

Tags: python, lambda

I  am given a bunch of tuples inside a 2d-list. Given (x,y,z), find the tuple with the highest y*z and return the corresponding x.

Example:

```
[[1,...("9744", 9, 44.95)], 
[2, ... ("9744", 9, 44.95)]...]

Multiply 9 and 44.95:
[[1,...("9744", 9, 44.95)], 
[2, ... ("9744", 9, 44.95)]...]

[[1,...("9744", 809.1)], 
[2, ... ("9744", 809.1)]...]
```

Now we know "9744" has the highest value inside their tuple out of all tuples.

I have done so using max() and various lambda functions. I would like not to change up my code too much, and would like some tips on how to proceed from here.

```
orders = [[1, ("5464", 4, 9.99), ("8274",18,12.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
           [2, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
           [3, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("88112", 11, 24.99)],
           [4, ("8732", 7, 11.99), ("7733",11,18.99), ("88112", 5, 39.95)]]
```

My code:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: (max(list(map(lambda a: (a[0], a[1]+a[1]),(list(map(lambda y: (y[0], y[1]*y[2]), x[1:]))))))), orders)))
```

My output:

```
[('9744', 809.1), ('9744', 809.1), ('88112', 549.78), ('88112', 399.5)]
```

Desired output:

```
["9744", 809.1]
```

I am wondering, what would be the most efficient way to collapse my output values to get the desired output. Would I have to implement an if-statement here?

Comment: "I am to find the highest value represented by the string inside the tuples, by multiplying the integers inside the tuples." This is where I check out mentally. What has the string to do with the product of the ints?

Comment: @timgeb English is not my first language, If my desired output has the string infront of the result of the product. Is that not worded correctly then?

Comment: The highest int encoded as a string is "88112", why is it "9744" in the desired output?

Comment: @timgeb Please let me know, if my edit makes up for what I am trying to explain.

Comment: So given a bunch of tuples `(x, y, z)`, find the tuple with the highest `y*z` and return the corresponding `x`?

Comment: @chepner yes thats exactly it. Thank you, I'll use this wording my questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can just take `max` and then `list` the result: `list(max(<your code>))`

cleaning up a bit, that would be:

```
list(max(map(lambda p: (max(map(lambda t: (t[0], 2*t[1]*t[2]), p[1:]))), orders)))
```

or using generator comprehension:

```
list(max( max( (k, 2 * v*w) for k, v, w in tps ) for _, *tps in orders ))
```